# grep exits due to ram usage - can I make grep not use so much ram?

Tags: grep, ram

I had an operation that works thru originallist (dowork.sh originallist), and lets you know what it has finished into cleaned1. cleaned1 is sorted differently than originallist. I need to generate a list of what's left for dowork.sh to process. Essentially: list cleanedR - list cleaned1 = list cleaned2. It's a minus operation. I found that I can do that operation with the following grep options:

- F for full line match instead of regular expression (we don't want grep freaking out at filename characters thinking they are regular expressions),
- v for exclude (which is the minus operation),
- f for look thru the file cleaned1 for the expressions instead of a single given expression ("obtain PATTERN from FILE").

---

```
# wc -l cleaned*
 9157094 cleaned1
 14283591 cleanedR

# du -sh cleaned*
1.3G    cleaned1
2.0G    cleanedR

# grep -Fvf cleaned1 originallist > cleaned2
```

runs for 5 minutes, uses up 42G of ram or less but a lot of it, then exits with failure; cleaned2 is 0 bytes long.

cleaned2 at the end should be 14283591 - 9157094 = 5126497 lines long

This is the correct syntax for doing such an operation (I tested it with a 10 line long cleanedR and a 3 line long cleaned1; the resultant cleaned2 was 7 lines), however it uses up a lot of ram. Is there a way to make this work by making grep not use up so much ram? I know it will take a while, but I am okay with it.

I am looking for something like sort's -T option, which allows you to not use up /tmp (ram in my case), and allow you to use another directory

```
sort -h
 -T, --temporary-directory=DIR  use DIR for temporaries, not $TMPDIR or /tmp;
                                multiple options specify multiple directories
```

Comment: Does the order of stuff in cleaned2 matter? If not, then sort cleaned1 and originallist and use `comm`.

Comment: Does adding the grep  `-x` option help?

Answer (score 4):

The sort command has some specific support for working with huge data sets because that's a relatively common use case. Huge grep patterns is an extremely uncommon use case so you can't hope for the developers to have put a lot of effort into it.

If the order of lines doesn't matter, you can sort the two files, after which they can be compared without storing more than a few lines in memory at a time, no matter how long the files are. Since sort can cope with files that don't fit in memory, this is efficient.

```
sort originallist >originallist.sorted
sort cleaned1 | comm -23 originallist.sorted - >cleaned2.sorted
```

If the original order of originallist matters, you can add line numbers to it:

```
nl -w 22 originallist >originallist.numbered
# then generate cleaned1 from the numbered list
```

Since `originallist.numbered` is sorted, you can run `comm` on it to detect common lines.

If the order matters and it's too late to number the lines, then you could try splitting `cleaned1` into chunks and making one pass into `originallist` for each chunk. With a recent GNU split:

```
cp originalfile cleaned2.in
split -l 1000000 --filter='grep -Fxv -f - cleaned2.in >cleaned2.out; mv cleaned2.out cleaned2.in' cleaned1
mv cleaned2.in cleaned2
```

(Note that `F` does not do “full line match”, it does a substring match. For a full line string match, you need `-x` as well.)